# Listify Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Hi I am building a directory with listify and would like to remove ads if a listing has a subscription:

I am looking for a conditional tag for wp job manager or listify to check if a listing has a subscription.

I know that if there is the has_woocommerce_subscription conditional to check if a user has a subscription.

Could I use that to check if a listing owner has a subscription?

I am using woocommerce, WooCommerce Subscriptions and wpjobmanager.

Basically

```
has_woocommerce_subscription(wp_get_current_listing($the_listing_id), $the_product_id, 'active') {
display this 
else
display that
}
```